# Sincronizar datos remotos en aplicación Android: Sync Adapters, Proveedor de contenidos (Content Provider), Base de Datos

Tags: android

Yo tengo actualmente una App Android que presenta contenido obtenido desde una base de datos remota MySQL.

El contenido es pedido desde la App al servidor usando Volley, mediante diferentes puntos de entrada que consultan a la base de datos y devuelven la respuesta en formato JSON. La app hace el *parse*  y presenta los datos.

Todo eso funciona bien... pero la app necesita estar conectada a internet obligatoriamente para funcionar.

Yo me estoy planteando ahora la posibilidad de que el contenido que consume la app (que reside en una base de datos MySQL en el servidor) pueda existir y ser sincronizado también localmente en la app, de modo que ésta pueda mostrar el contenido cuando no haya conexión a internet.

Estuve leyendo sobre el tema en la documentación de Android, pero no logro aclararme entre lo de `Sync Adapter`, `Content Provider` ... y demás familiares.

De lo que he leído, comprendo que en mi caso hay dos posibilidades interesantes:

- a. Sincronizar mi base de datos remota (MySQL) con una base de datos local en la app (SQLite)
- b. Sincronizar carpetas con los archivos JSON que necesita la app

Yo había pensando en un primer momento implementar la opción b, creando un script en el servidor que me escriba por ejemplo todos los JSON del mes en curso en diferentes carpetas y sincronizar esas carpetas en local con la app. Desde la app yo implementaría algo para ir limpiando los archivos viejos cada X meses o algo así.

La opción a sería quizá la mejor. La base de datos garantiza la no redundancia de datos, pues los JSON de la opción b tendrían al final información repetida, dado que el contenido es cíclico y se repite cada X días o semanas según el caso y habría más tráfico de información sólo para usar y tirar ya que, el JSON de ayer ya hoy sería de una utilidad casi nula para todos los usuarios.

Con la opción a, quizá ¿gane en rapidez con respecto a un JSON? ¿usaría menos el sincronizador (esto casi seguro que sí)?

Pero opción a tiene un problema, al menos por ahora (según imagino y **esta es una de mis principales dudas**): la app maneja muchas tablas y **no sé si para el proveedor de contenidos debo programar el código que extrae/maneja de la información de todas esas tablas**.

Lo que quisiera saber es básicamente:

- ¿Alguien ha experimentado con soluciones parecidas a las opciones **a** o **b** antes mencionadas?
- ¿Sugerirían alguna otra solución al problema planteado (descartando soluciones de pago como `Firebase` porque está fuera de mi alcance, económicamente)?
- En el caso de decidirme por la sincronización entre la base de datos remota y la local, ¿cuál sería la mejor forma de hacer esto, existen herramientas que ayuden, tendría que crear proveedores de contenido por cada tabla?

Espero que la pregunta no sea demasiado amplia, son muchas dudas sobre un mismo problema y no sé como abordar este caso optando por la mejor solución.

Entre las cosas que he leído, pero sin encontrar una solución óptima para mi caso:

- [Transfer data using sync adapters](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/)
- [Conceptos básicos sobre el proveedor de contenido](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics)
- [Creación de un proveedor de contenido](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating)

Comment: Yo por no complicarme lo que haría sería: una vez realizada la llamada para obtener el json con los datos crearía una función que lo guarde también en local (de forma asíncrona para no impactar en la velocidad de búsqueda). Es decir, crear una especie de backup. Luego cada vez que llames al servicio de obtención comprueba si hay internet. Si no lo hay cargas el backup. Aunque claro, depende bastante del volumen que estés recuperando y de la complejidad que quieras alcanzar.

Comment: @Corpex los JSON son muy pequeños, pero aquí la idea es tener varios JSON presentes ya en local por medio de un servicio de sincronización. Fíjate que me ha escrito gente que vive en Cuba y me han pedido esto, supongamos que ellos se pueden conectar una vez al mes a internet o una vez a la semana. La idea es que, cuando el usuario X se conecte, el servicio sincronice el contenido disponible en el servidor: el contenido de 1 mes, de 2 mese, de 3 meses, de 6 meses, de 1 año.

Comment: Lograste resolverlo? tengo exactamente la misma situacion y no se por donde empezar

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez aún no, sigo investigando y por falta de tiempo tampoco he podido hacer ensayos. Cuando lo resuelva tengo pensado aportar la solución en una respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano he implementado un modulo de sincronizacion usando JSON y una API REST y funciona pero sigo buscando una manera mas eficaz.. sera que has probado algo mas?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez [aquí está lo que buscaba](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide). Hay una explicación completa y en castellano de todos los pasos a seguir, basada en nuevos conceptos introducidos en Android hace poco. Ahora falta implementarlo. Dado que es un terreno desconocido pienso ahora lanzar una nueva versión de mi App sin persistencia hasta que pueda afrontar el problema de una forma definitiva. Aunque me interesaría saber en qué consiste tu módulo de sincronización basado en JSON y REST. He pensado en algo parecido como solución temporal, pero no tengo claro cómo hacerlo.