# como compartir una Base da datos con otra aplicacion android usando ShareUserID?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Tengo dos aplicaciones android que serán usadas en el mismo dispositivo, la primera app fue lanzada hace mas de 5 años ahora la nueva app debe leer alguna información de la otra app, he logrado hacerlo colocando, ambas aplicaciones trabajan offline

```
android:sharedUserId="com.myapp"
```

En el `Manifest.xml` de ambas applicaciones, he hecho pruebas y funciona bien, el problema es que al agregar esa linea en el manifest de la primera app me da un error a la hora de compilar:

[image: error]

Entiendo que este error se solventa instalando la app nuevamente, pero no puedo hacer eso, como podria solventar este error?

Comment: Hasta donde he podido ver, no hay manera de resolver este tema. Una posible alternativa para compartir información entre aplicaciones es utilizar contentProviders, sin cambiar el `android:sharedUserId` de la aplicación antigua.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455977/255257

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33305537/255257

Comment: No lo sabia, muchas gracias por la informacion

Comment: La pregunta clave aquí es si tienes potestad para modificar el código de la App antigua. Si no la tienes y la misma no fue programada para usar un `ContentProvider` será imposible por ese medio acceder a los datos de la base de datos. En ese caso (según he leído pero no probado) tendrías que saltarte una regla de seguridad de Android: dar permisos de lectura (y escritura si fuera necesario) a esa BD, haciendo uso de los derechos de administrador. Entonces sí se podrá acceder a la base de datos desde otra app. Android bloquea ese acceso desde fuera precisamente por el riesgo que supondría.

Comment: Si tengo la posibilidad de programar ambas app, pero no se si un content provider solucione mi problema

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no crees que solucione tu problema? El `ContentProvider` existe precisamente para manejar este tipo de situaciones de forma segura. [Revisa la documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics?hl=es-419). A no ser que quieras hacer evolucionar tus apps y trasladar la fuente de datos a un lugar común donde ambas puedan acceder, algo así como una BD remota, Firebase, AWS u otros.

Comment: Lo revisare, muchas gracias

Comment: Aunque no entiendo por qué una App tiene que ser ¿propietaria? de la BD y compartirla con otra ¿? ¿Por qué no trasladar la BD a un entorno común (Firebase, BD Remota, etc) y que cada App tenga acceso a ella de forma independiente?

Comment: Ah el detalle es que trabajan offline y cada cierto tiempo sincronizan con el servidor remoto

Comment: Si hay un servidor remoto no entiendo por qué las dos Apps tienen que compartir datos entre ellas ¿? ¿Por qué no toman los datos del servidor remoto? Allí puedes tener todo centralizado y al día para las dos Apps o para mil Apps si fuera preciso. Y si se requieren datos off-line es mejor trabajar seriamente en un código de **sincronización**. Sé que este es para muchos, también para mí, el gran dolor de cabeza de Android, de hecho [tengo algo pendiente con eso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/173902/29967). Al menos ya sé como hacerlo, pero no dispongo ahora del tiempo para hacerlo.

Answer (score 3):

En cuanto a el mensaje:

> installation failed with message failed to finalize session :
>   INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE

**es importante firmar ambas aplicaciones con el mismo certificado.**

Te sugiero revisar la información acerca de [android:sharedUserId](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid):

> [android:sharedUserId](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) El nombre de un ID de usuario de Linux que
>   se compartirá con otras aplicaciones. De forma predeterminada, Android
>   asigna a cada aplicación su propia ID de usuario única. Sin embargo,
>   si este atributo se establece en el mismo valor para dos o más
>   aplicaciones, todas compartirán la misma ID, siempre que sus conjuntos
>   de certificados sean idénticos. Las aplicaciones con el mismo ID de
>   usuario pueden acceder a los datos de los demás y, si lo desea,
>   ejecutarse en el mismo proceso.

La mejor solución en base a lo que deseas realizar:

> como compartir una Base da datos con otra aplicacion android

es mediante un proveedor de contenido [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics), para leer información de una aplicación es necesario definir la autorización dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.MyApplication">

   <application
      ...
      ...
      ...
            >

      <provider android:name="AppProvider"
         android:authorities="com.example.AppProvider"/>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

[**ContentProvider en Android**](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/content-providers-en-android-i-construccion/)